# Why does Flutter's StateNotifier only allow immutable values?

Tags: flutter

Flutter's StateNotifier only allows immutable values. But I doubt it. Because the StateNotifierProvider may be subscribed to from multiple screens, and if it is subscribed to from multiple screens, I thought that a mutable value would be better, where the changes span multiple screens. (You may want to update a user's login status, for example, on multiple screens at the same time.)
(If you want to be notified of changes to multiple screens, I think it would be more convenient to have a mutable value that has a common reference to multiple screens.
Why does StateNotifier only allow immutable values?